# Does multiplying by the zero vector ALWAYS yield the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

Basically, I got in an argument with my professor over a test question.

> Let V be the set of all positive real numbers with opertaions $\vec X + \vec Y = \vec X\vec Y$,
>   and $k\vec X = \vec X^k  $.  Verify the 10 axioms to show that V is a vector space

My solution went as follows:

For the 5th axiom,

> For each $\vec u$ in V, there is an object $-\vec u$ in V, called a negative of $\vec u$, such that $\vec u+(-\vec u) = (-\vec u)+\vec u = 0$

I used the fact that I found the zero vector to be 1 in the previous step ($\vec 0 = \vec 1$), and stated that since addition becomes multiplication, and that multiplication by zero vector yields zero vector, then $-\vec X = \vec 1.$
$$ \vec X+ -\vec X= \vec 0 \\ 
-\vec X\vec X= \vec0\\
\text{Since multiplication by zero vector equals zero vector, $-\vec X = \vec 1$} $$
My professor stated that my answer was incorrect and that the right answer is

$$ \vec x + (-\vec x) = \vec 0\\
\vec x + \frac 1  {\vec x}\\
\frac {\vec x} {\vec x} = \vec 0\\
\vec 1= \vec 0 $$

This left me very confused.

1- why is my answer wrong? is it not true that multiplication by zero vector yields zero vector?

2- is it correct to say that $ \vec X \frac {\vec 1} {\vec X} = \vec 1$ when the rules for vector multiplication were not even mentioned in the problem?

thanks

Comment: Your solution to what? There isn't a question, just some definition.

Comment: Apologies , i just fixed it.

Comment: I don't understand your operations. What does multiplication of vectors mean?

Comment: Aren't you confusing the identity of multiplication with the identity for addition? Also, division with vectors is typically not defined.

Comment: Multiplication of vectors is not defined for a bare vector space. Multiplication of a vector by a scalar is, but that’s not what you’re working with in trying to verify the axiom. I think the notation in the definitions of vector addition and scalar multiplication are a bit sloppy as they mix up the interpretations of a real number as a vector in this vector space and as a real number qua real number. I would instead write $\vec X+\vec Y=XY$ and $k\vec X=X^k$ to make clearer which role $X$ and $Y$ are playing where.

Comment: That's the part that confused me, the problem never stated anything about vector multiplication. but the professor used the fact that 1/x * x = 1 = 0

Comment: @lovsovs This is a notation nightmare but essentially this is just a way of representing  $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot, \cdot . )$ using vector algebra notation . The right hand side entities are really to be viewed as regular reals with regular operations.

Comment: In any case, is it true to say that multiplication by zero vector yields zero vector. Because it's just like every body here stated, his notation is a nightmare. my only hope of regaining any of my lost points is to argue the general case that no matter of how multiplication is defined, In a vector space, multiplying by the zero vector must yield the zero vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's been some confusion arising from notation and also some confusion between vector operations and real number operations. It's a bit difficult for me to see exactly where the confusion is taking place in your case, but I'll respond to each of your questions in turn with my own way of thinking about it.

Following @amd's advice, whenever talking about an object in a *vector* sense, I will render it with the vector arrow on top ($\vec x$), otherwise the operations refer to the standard operations among real numbers. Hence we may write the definition of vector addition and scalar multiplication like so:
\begin{align}
\vec x + \vec y &:= xy \\
k \vec x &:= x^k
\end{align}
where $k$ can denote *any* real number (positive or negative)

1. For any vector space, multiplication by the *scalar* zero returns the zero *vector*. You can see that in our case this way: Let $\vec x$ denote any vector in our space (i.e. a positive real number). Then
   \begin{align}
   0 \vec x := x^0 = 1 = \vec 0
   \end{align}
   And $1$ is the correct *vector* zero in our case since raising any positive real number to the power $1$ (i.e. *adding* it in the *vector* sense) returns the original input:
   \begin{align}
   \vec x + \vec 1 &= x^1 = x = \vec x \\
   \therefore 1 &= \vec 0
   \end{align}
2. $\vec x \frac{1}{\vec x} = \vec 1$ is really bad notation. But it is "correct" if interpreted properly. I would write the interpretation like so:
   \begin{align}
   \vec x + (-\vec x) = x \cdot \frac{1}{x} = 1 = \vec 0
   \end{align}
   Hence $-\vec x = \frac{1}{x}$: i.e. the *vector* negative is the *real* reciprocal, and so the notation $x \cdot \frac{1}{x}$ (without the arrows) is well-defined because here we are talking about multiplication among *real* numbers, not vectors.

Comment: If that was true, then the 5th axiom would not be satisfied, since when multiplying by scalar, we change the "vector" into a scalar and raise it to the power of the multiplying scalar. and if we do that, then we won't be able to add them, since we would be adding a vector to a scalar, which does not make sense. Pay close attention to the following notation. $ \vec X + (-\vec X) => \vec X + x^{-1} $ this doesn't make sense. am I right?

Comment: I think the trouble here is the *same* objects that are vectors (the positive reals) can be used at the same time as scalars. But we can shift between the two interpretations as we please (as long as we do it carefully). If you choose to interpret the expression $\vec x + x^{-1}$ as a vector plus a scalar, then it is ill-defined as you say. But remember $x^{-1}$ can also be thought of as a *vector* in our space. Hence $\vec x + x^{-1} = x \cdot x^{-1} = 1 = \vec 0$ by definition.

Comment: That is, $\vec x+\vec{1/x}=x\cdot 1/x$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be even clearer using upper-case or bold for vectors and unadorned lower-case for scalars and reals?

Comment: @amd Maybe. But I almost wonder if it might be better to strip the arrows, caps, and/or boldface altogether so no confusion arises about adding scalars to vectors when they are really vectors to vectors (or scalars to scalars). Perhaps the best thing would be to write vector addition as $\oplus$?

Answer (score 0):

A vector space is of the form $(V,F, +,\times)$ where $V$ is the set of vectors, $F$ is the set of scalars, $+$ is addition of vectors, and $\times$ is multiplication of vectors by scalars.

Consider  the vector space $\mathbb V_1=(V_1,F,+_1,\times_1)=(\mathbb R,\mathbb R,+,\times)$  where $+$ and $\times$ are the usual addition and multiplication in $\mathbb R.$

Consider $\mathbb R^+$ with operations $x+_2y=xy$  and $k\times_2x= x\times_2k= x^k$ for $x\in \mathbb R^+$ and $k\in \mathbb  R.$

The function $f(y)=e^y$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb V_1$ to $\mathbb V_2=(\mathbb R^+, \mathbb R, +_2,\times_2).$

That is $f:V_1\to \mathbb R^+$ is a bijection which preserves the algebra, i.e. $f(x+_1y)=f(x)+_2f(y)$ and $f(k\times_1x)=k\times_2f(x)=f(x)\times_2 k$ for $x,y\in V_1$ and $k\in F.$ So $\mathbb V_2$ is also a vector space.